# Using Fatfs to write an array of uint32_t

Tags: c, microcontroller, freertos, lpc

I have FreeRTOS on LPC microcontroller. I have an array of size 10 of type uint32_t. I want to write this array to the SD card using f_write. I can write text Successfully, but whenever I try to write the array it always writes garbage. How can I write the array with a space between each value?

Thanks @user694733 for the help. I used the sprintf function to convert to strings, and now it writes fine. Also is there any way to convert the array inside a loop. This is what I am doing right now

so to convert the 10 values I am first writing them to the array, and then using sprintf like this

```
array[index] = values; 
index += 1; 

sprintf(buffer,"%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5],array[6],array[7],array[8],array[9]);
```

is there anyway to do this

```
sprintf(buffer, ",%lu,",array[index]);
```

Comment: What's the problem with just writing simple, straightforward code to do exactly what you want? Why is this a problem? Assemble exactly the bytes you want to appear in the file in memory and then `f_write` those bytes.

Comment: So do you want to write this array as binary data, or do you want to convert your 10 uint32_t values to text and then write the text to a file ? What did you do (show your code) and what do you need help with regarding that code ?

Answer (score 0):

`f_write` writes data in binary format.

If you want to output in text format, then convert numbers to strings with [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) first, or use FatFS [`f_printf`](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/printf.html) which supports a subset of normal printf -functionality.